# How to bind an array contains string to oracle query (IN clause) using any method(oci/pdo) in PHP?

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I have an array as the described below :

> array is $number

```
array(84) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(10) "12345678" [2]=> string(10) "12345679" [3]=> string(10) "12345610" [4]=> string(10) "12345611" [5]=> string(10) "12345612" [6]=> string(10) "12345613" [7]=> string(10) "12345614"}
```

Now, I want to make the array bind to my sql query as the desribed below :

```
$sql = " SELECT    id, 
    FROM      cust_data
    WHERE     whatever IN (:number)";
```

I've tried using the following method :

```
$stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); //Query SQL    
$idCollection = oci_new_collection($conn, 'ODCINUMBERLIST', 'SYS');
    foreach ($number as $num) {
        $idCollection->append($num);
    }
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':number', $idCollection,-1, SQLT_NTY);
    oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);
    oci_fetch_all($stid,$result);
    var_dump( $result);
```

But it just give me the result

> array(0) { }

Thank you.

Comment: you need to bind each value separately into the IN clause for it to be considered separately. Right now your SQL ends up in the form `whatever IN ('A, B, C, D')` i.e. as if it's all one string, whereas I think you actually want `whatever IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')` i.e. to be considered as separate items in the IN clause.

Comment: So I think you'll need to loop your array and build up the IN clause parameters gradually in the SQL string, and also add to the parameter list gradually at the same time.

Comment: yap its certainly what i want and thanks for the solution, now i'm trying to use this code but still its given empty result `oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':msisdn', $v, 200);
foreach ($msisdn as $v) {
    $r = oci_execute($stid, OCI_DEFAULT);  // don't auto commit
}
oci_commit($conn); // co
json_encode($r);` . maybe I'm too newbie for this.

Comment: why are you executing the query multiple times? And I don't know what your data is, so I can't tell you if you actually have any matching rows or not. And why are you using a "commit" for a SELECT query?

Answer (score 0):

See "Binding Multiple Values in an IN Clause" p p169 of the free book from Oracle https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html

In summary, for a small number of values, use a fixed SQL string with bind variables.  Bind null if there are fewer data values than actual bind variables in the SQL.  For bigger lists you can build up a SQL string: but still use bind variables.